# Trouble Saving JWT Token on Client Side in Flask Project

Tags: python, flask, jwt, token, access-token

I have an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

Let's keep it simple. In a fresh Flask project, I have a `hello_world` method to create a **token**:

```py
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    access_token = create_access_token(identity=1)
    return jsonify(access_token=access_token)
```

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTcwNTI0Mjc2MiwianRpIjoiOTE2ZmYwMzMtMTFjMC00ZTJkLWJjN2MtMDUwYWVlMWFlZDIyIiwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInN1YiI6MSwibmJmIjoxNzA1MjQyNzYyLCJjc3JmIjoiYjljMTM3MjItM2IyMS00NzgxLTgwMzUtODQ0NTkwZjIwOTdmIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA1MzI5MTYyfQ.D7019NWeRt7INt5hwseifE148x_wfVHU1fCr9E1yEJs"
}
```

From what I understand, the `create_access_token` method (from the jwt library) is supposed to handle token storage on its own. However, I'm also attempting to store it using JavaScript.

Then, I have another route that requires this token to access the page:

```py
@user_blueprint.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def get_users():
    return UserController.get_users()
```

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to save the token on the client's browser! Here's what the browser gives me:

```
{
  "msg": "Missing Authorization Header"
}
```

I hope someone can help me out a bit. Thanks for your assistance.

- I'd like to point out that I'm working on an API, but on postman everything works when I enter the token manually.

Comment: Your problem seems to be on the clients side. So, show as the client and not the server code.

Comment: @KlausD.  I'm working on an API, there's no client side, and even if there had been I'd created a page using this route, the problem would still be the same. The token is never saved on the browser

Comment: The browser does not safe JWTs, except you tell it to in client code (JavaScript).

Comment: OK, but how do I find out the key to the jwt token?
When I use the token on postman, I don't need to specify it. But in javascript you have to give a name to the key and its value, which is our hashed token

[image web](https://imgur.com/B9LG2ec.png)

For example, when I enter it manually, I still can't access the page, unlike postman

[image postman](https://imgur.com/PuFmj0v.png)

Comment: To make myself clearer: You have to access to whole API in JavaScript incl. setting the header(s). The browser alone can not handle a REST API.

Comment: Save `access_token` to local storage and put in header `Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}` before your client call api

Comment: OK, on the backend of my site I made the request to retrieve this token.
I managed to store the token as a cookie directly in the template using javascript.
But now if I want to retrieve this token on the server side of the site, i.e. outside the template, the route for example.
I can't find a method for extracting this cookie.
Or if I have to extract it in javascript on the template, how do I send it to my site back-end (route)?